# Turn Stepper Motor Off when Idle

Tags: motor, driver, stepper-motor

I was wondering if there is a way to cut power to my stepper motor when it is not in use. I dont particularlily need it to hold its position because in my setup it doesnt really need to torque agaisnt any outside force when its idle, and it also has a a sensor to indicate position so losing steps isn't the end of the world.

I thought of having a relay cut power to the VCC of the H-Bridge Motor Driver. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: As always, specific details, circuits, links, biographies, family photos,  family tree and general histories of the setup and components (or such of these as may be relevant) helps people give you appropriate answers. As it is, WRB's answer is potentially correct but the best answer so far is, "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

The driver almost certainly has an enable line. Setting that line to "not-enabled" ought to turn the current off.